# A get or set accessor expected - how do I fix this?

Tags: c#

```
private static IEnumerable<Image> Images
{
    get
    {
       return new Image
       {
          Resources.img1;
          Resources.img2;
          Resources.img3;
          Resources.img4;
          Resources.img5;
          Resources.img6;
          Resources.img7;
          Resources.img8;               
       };
    }
}<---here I get "} expected "- why?
```

Comment: I guess you need `return new List<Image>`

Answer (score 2):

Use the symbol `,` instead of `;` in the list initilisation. And return a `List<Image>` as @Habib says.

Answer (score 1):

You should return collection of images from getter, not single Image object. Try this one instead:

```
private static IEnumerable<Image> Images
{
    get
    {
        return new List<Image>
        {
            Resources.img1,
            Resources.img2,
            Resources.img3,
            Resources.img4,
            Resources.img5,
            Resources.img6,
            Resources.img7,
            Resources.img8               
        };
    }
}
```